# Is it possible to detect the hardware of an internet connected server using your web browser?

Tags: linux, security, web-server, remote-desktop, remote-access

Information like hardware configuration, running OS version, etc. of a data center server connected to the internet? Basically, I am more interested in knowing data center cluster, their locations & their server configurations of a cellular company (ISP), the submarine cables they are connected to, & an overall network graph.

Comment: are you talking about scanning a company's whole network and mapping all of their devices/cables/routes using your browser??

Comment: only the major data center locations & network map between these centers, plus the international routes of traffic. Nothing professional, just curious.

Comment: I should have added more "?" symbols so the irony was easier to understand.

Comment: Okay I'm not an expert, just wanted to know the scope till which these can be determined.

Comment: I do have managed to collect some info about them from reverse whois & all, was curious about the servers. :)

Comment: In the future, make some research before asking others and you might not even need to do it then. (Just to avoid making "stupid" questions)

Answer (score 1):

You can find some things in the header of the content.

Go to https://www.monitostech.com/tool/http

Enter a webpage, you can learn some info like whether they use Apache or IIS, or what .Net version they use.

Keep in mind that header information can be changed by the server admin, so you might get information that is not correct, on purpose, although you can usually do other tests to figure out what kind of server they are using.

If you are looking for things like CPU count and hard drive space, those may be exposed if your server runs a hardware maintenance service that is inadvertently accessible form the internet.

Comment: good luck finding anything true/relevant with that method on a real company :P

Comment: I 100% agree, but it is often overlooked by many.